# Multi page pdf with dynamic text jspdf fromHTML pagebreaks

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am generating a pdf document using jspdf from a bunch of different forms(about 20) that may or may not be included in the pdf depending on if the user chooses them. I am using the fromHTML() function to dynamically add the form questions and answers to an html page which will then get converted to a pdf. I finally got the formatting to look how i wanted it to, however when the content goes beyond one page(which it almost always will) there is a line which gets cut off in between the two pages. Each form has a size ranging from 5-12 questions and each question has the possibility of having notes attatched with no set limit. At the end of each form is an additional notes section. Because of this, I dont know when to add page breaks or call doc.addPage(). I've seen similar issues to this online but failed to find a proper solution.

I can add this piece of code

```
$('<p>---PAGE BREAK---</p>').insertAfter('.A_2 p:nth-child(16)');
```

which more or less inserts a dummy paragraph that I don't care gets cut out. I can only do this after I know where it cuts though.

Now I need to know a way to figure out when to insert that dummy paragagraph if the content reaches the end of the page, or some other way to add page breaks based on dynamic text.